# Show that $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & -3\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}4 & 7 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ is another orthogonal basis of $U$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $X=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 & 1 & 6\end{bmatrix}$ in $R4$, and let $U=span\left\{\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 3 & -4\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$.
Show that $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & -3\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}4 & 7 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ is another orthogonal basis of $U$.

I tried the Gram-Schmidt algorithm method, but since $X1=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 3 & -4\end{bmatrix}=E1$ is different from $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & -3\end{bmatrix}$, I don't think it's the right approach. Any help?

Comment: What does $X$ have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

1. check that the dimension of $U$ is 2.
2. check that $[1, 0, 2, -3], [4,7,1,2]$ are elements of $U$.
3. check that they are orthogonal.

Comment: 1) dim U= 2 because U span two vectors right?

Comment: Im genuinely lost

Comment: Since $U= span \{ [2,1,3,4], [1,2,0,1] \}$ and the two vectors are independent, hence the dimension is $2$.

Comment: I believe you must also check that $[1,0,2,-3],[4,7,1,2]$ are also linearly independent-this follows from $3$, but the OP may not have proven that yet.

Comment: @DavidWheeler, yup, I agree we have to check for independence. It eithers come from 3 or just notice that the two non-zero vectors are not multiples of each oher

Answer (score 0):

The vectors $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are linearly independent.

The vectors $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are in the $\mathbf{U}$ basis:
$$
v_{1}=
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
  1 \\
  0 \\
  2 \\
 -3 \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\frac{2}{3} 
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 2  \\
 1 \\
 3  \\
 -4 
\end{array}
\right]
-
\frac{1}{3} 
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1 \\
 2 \\
 0 \\
 1 
\end{array}
\right], \qquad
%
v_{2}=
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
  4 \\
  7 \\
  1 \\
  2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\frac{1}{3} 
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 2  \\
 1 \\
 3  \\
 -4 
\end{array}
\right]
+
\frac{10}{3} 
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1 \\
 2 \\
 0 \\
 1 
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The vectors are orthogonal:
$$
 v_{1} \cdot v_{2} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
  1 &
  0 &
  2 &
 -3 
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
  4 \\
  7 \\
  1 \\
  2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
4+0+2-6= 0
$$